# Override Model property or method in laravel using service provider

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel 5.2 and want to override a property of framework model, I have lot of models and don't want to go each of them and override.

```
i:e protected $dateformat; // I don't want to write this in all of my models.
```

I have a solution in my mind,

Either, I create my own basemodel and extend all my models from this class and override a property in that basemodel like.

```
class MyBaseModel extends Model {
    protected $dateformat;
}

class Employee extends MyBaseModel {
}
```

But, is there any other method like creating a service provider?

Comment: Extending the Model Class with your own base class would be your best option

Comment: I am also using spark, and spark use its own models, So I have to change the spark models as well.isn't there any other solution so that I can achieve my desired output?